# Texture2D.GetData<Color> throws NotImplementedException on Linux

Tags: monodevelop, monogame

I am developing a Linux game. I try trying to use GetData from a Texture2D, but I get a NotImplementedException. Details:

```
System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D.GetData[Color] (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color[] data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 0):

Texture2D.GetData is not implemented on all platforms. I can't speak for the Linux implementation directly but there's a few related discussions on github that might shed some light on the matter for you.

https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/1091

https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/1405